# render iframe html code from model to django template

Tags: python, django, iframe

I have a django project for showing details of Movie theaters in various location where i want to show the location iframe in template, And I want to save the complete html code for iframe in my model and render it into the template respectively for different theaters.

I have created a model where i take the details of theater.

**models.py**

```
class theater(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],max_length=15,unique=True)
    landline = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True,validators=[phone_regex])
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text="enter E-Mail address",null=True,blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=300, help_text="enter website link",null=True,blank=True)
    iframe_detail=models.TextField(max_length=5000)
```

In the details page of my theater i am able to render all the details but not the location from iframe, below is my template.html

**theater_detail.html**

```
<h1>Name: {{theater.name}}</h1><br>
<h1>Name: {{theater.mobile }}</h1><br>
<h1>Name: {{theater.email }}</h1><br>
<h1>Name: {{theater.website }}</h1><br>
<div class="w-100">
       {{theater.iframe_detail|safe}}             
</div>
```

The iframe data what i am loading in my model is below.
**eg**

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3806.9740157153647!2d78.46347561744385!3d17.413034599999996!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bcb975afb4afadd%3A0xf89ea8407df6c84!2sPrasads%20Multiplex!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1595574993123!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use you field in HTML turn off your '**autoescape**' tag

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{theater.iframe_detail}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

this will allow HTML in models filed to display as HTML tags